# Bash command / Python script to add Target Dependencies to Xcode Project

Tags: python, bash, command-line, xcode10

Here is my Xcode project structure Main Project(SampleApp), Sub project (Framework Source App). I need to add this out put framework of sub project as a Target dependency to the main project using bash command / python script, as of now I am doing it manually, but I would like to automate this process, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.